# Items from dataGrid to string

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid, items

I'm looking for a way to get the `SelectedItems` from a `DataGrid` into a comma separated string that can be passed into an automated process.

In my code, I have a `DataGrid1`, then a second `DataGrid2` that is bound to the `SelectedItems` from the first list. Then a `TextBox` that is bound to the the `Items` of the second list.

Here is my `DataGrid`:

```
<!-- items source based on selection of another data grid -->
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid2" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid,Path=SelectedItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  SelectionMode="Extended"  Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Items"  Width="Auto" >
            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0},{1},{2};">
                    <Binding XPath="ProjectOrderNo"/>
                    <Binding XPath="Style" />
                    <Binding XPath="CustomerNo" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Then binding to the `Items` into a `TextBox` using the following binding

```
<TextBox x:Name="txt0" Text="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid2,Path=Items, Mode=OneWay}" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />
```

the result is the `TextBox` displaying "(Collection)". I am unsure how to parse out the (Collection) as a comma separated string. Is this something that can be handled by a `Converter`? 
The string should be formatted like:

`Orderno`,`customerNo`,`ItemNo`;`Orderno`,`customerNo`,`ItemNo`;

which can be handled by a `StringBuilder`, but not having any luck getting the Items to process in the `Converter`..

Here's my first attempt:

```
public class SelectedItemsToString : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string[] arr = ((IEnumerable)value).Cast<object>()
                                             .Select(x => x.ToString())
                                             .ToArray();
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in arr)
        {
            builder.AppendFormat(",",item);
        }
        string result = builder.ToString();
        return arr.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: In the converter, why are you casting it into an object? Don't you have a class with the properties Orderno,customerNo,ItemNo;Orderno,customerNo,ItemNo?

Comment: I do not have a class for the properties.

Comment: What did you bind to the ItemsSourceProperty of the MyDatagrid1?

Comment: MyDataGrid1 is bound to data that is returned from an SQL webservice.

Comment: And that data that you get from the web service, is it a list or list of what List<?>? See, the ItemsSource property should allow you to bind to a collection or a list. So I suggest that you format the data you got from a web service such as ObservableCollection<Order>. Where order class has those properties that you mentioned.

Comment: Why tie your hands with having to parse a datagrid? Its obvious that the webservice data is returning a structure, or data, which at some level is known, otherwise how does grid2 know about how to display the data? I would work with the original data stream and avoid the grid2. Provide an example of Grid1's data.

Comment: it's simple XML data being returned. <root> <item><Value/><item/><item><Value/><item/></root>. My hands are tied because i am basically limited to using only XAML without any code-behind besides what has already been defined by the creators of the ERP i'm developing for. I am able to create a .dll  and deploy it as a feature that can be referenced in the XAML however.